# Failed to import defined modules in __init__.py

Tags: python, azure-functions, init

My directory looks like this :

```
- HttpExample:
    - __init__.py
    - DBConnection.py
    - getLatlong.py
```

I want to `import DBConnection` and `import getLatlong` in `__init__.py`. There is no error in my `__init__.py` until I run it, I received :

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpExample. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
>   Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'getLatlong'

I'm trying to use function in getLatlong to use the information input by user from `__init__.py` to `getLatlong`. Below is the code:

`__init__.py` :

```
from getLatlong import result
from DBConnection import blobService, container_name, account_key, file_path


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    section = req.params.get('section')
    bound = req.params.get('bound')
    km_location = req.params.get('km_location')
    location = req.params.get('location')
    if not section:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            section = req_body.get('section')

    if section and bound and km_location:

        result(section, km_location, bound, location).getResult() #HERE

        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {section}, {bound}!")

    #elif section is None or bound is None or km_location is None:
    #    return func.HttpResponse("All values are mandatory!")
```

I am also receiving compile error at `getLatlong` to import `DBConnection` to this class. The following values will pass to `getLatlong.py`. The code :

```
from DBConnection import blobService, container_name, account_key, file_path #Another import error here says : Unable to import DBConnection

class result:
    def __init__(self, section, bound, km_location, location):
        self.section = section
        self.bound = bound
        self.km_location = km_location
        self.location = location

    def getResult(self):

        print(self.section)
        print(self.bound)
        print(self.km_location)
        print(self.location)
```

I've tried every way to import these files before I lost my mind..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get these errors, because Python does not know where to look for the files you want to import. Depending on which Python version you are using, I see three ways to solve this:

1. You could add `HttpExample` to your PYTHONPATH and than your imports should work as you have them currently.
2. Another way would be to use the `sys` module and append the path to `HttpExample`, e.g.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('PATH/TO/HttpExample')
```

But you would have to do this in all files, where you want to import something from the parent folder.

3. Or you use relative imports, which have been available since Python 2.5 (See PEP238). Those are only available in modules, but as you have your `__init__.py` file, it should work. For relative imports you are using dots `.` to tell Python where to look for the import. One dot `.` tells Python to look for the desired import in the parent folder. You could also use `..` to go up two levels. But one level should be enough in your case.

So in your case changing your code to this, should solve your problem.

In `__init.py__`:

```
from .getLatlong import result
from .DBConnection import blobService, container_name, account_key, file_path
```

In `getLangLong.py`:

```
from .DBConnection import blobService, container_name, account_key, file_path
```

Comment: ughh now I feel stupid as hell stucked at this silly error. I tried your third suggestion last time but I kept getting `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` when I run `__init__` individually. So I run everything as a whole, it actually worked :((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((

Answer (score 0):

You could try `from __app__.HttpExample import getLatlong`.

There is a document about how to import module in the Shared Code folder. Check this doc:[Folder structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#folder-structure).

It says Shared code should be kept in a separate folder in `__app__`. And in my test this could work for me.